# Can you use bean validation 1.1 (JSR 349) in JBoss EAP 6.4.4?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, java-ee-6, bean-validation, jboss6.x

We are using bean validation in JBoss EAP 6.4.4 (resteasy & hibernate-validator 4) to validate REST payload data. As it seems JBoss 6.4.4 uses bean validation 1.0 which doesn't support method validation. So, requests are not being blocked by bean validation and reach the db. Is there any jboss deployment file or something similar where I can enable version 1.1? I cannot change the bundled libs because we'll lose jboss support for the AS. JBoss 7 seems to work out of the box, but it's still in alpha. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I would not recommend it since 1.1 has not been tested with the currently implemented CDI (Weld) in JBoss EAP 6.4.4. You will most likely run into errors/issues.

Comment: As CoolBeans suggested in a follow-up question, it's better not to update the libs http://stackoverflow.com/a/35071197/284263

Comment: Yes you can. See my answer here -
  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35091986/1308685

Comment: Yeah I actually tried your suggestion. I couldn't make jax-rs to work after removing the modules. But we've rolled back the versions anyway... Thanks